# CkEditor 5 not working with ReactJs 18.2.0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I'm working on a ReactJs (v18.2.0) project that requires integration with CkEditor5.

Following the official documentation [here](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/getting-started/frameworks/react.html#:%7E:text=The%20easiest%20way%20to%20use%20CKEditor%205%20in,CKEditor%205%20online%20builder%20in%20any%20React%20application.), I've imported and set up the CkEditor.

Somehow, it's not working. A log of the editor returns `null`

**CreateProduct.jsx**

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import { CKEditor } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react';
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';

...
<div>
    <CKEditor
        editor={ClassicEditor}
        data="<p>Hello World</p>"
        onReady={editor => {
            console.log(editor)
        }}
        onChange={(event, editor) => {
            console.log(editor.getData())
        }}

        onBlur={(event, editor) => {}}

        onFocus={(event, editor) => {}}
    />
</div>

...
export default CreateProduct;

if (document.getElementById('createProduct')) {

    const container = document.getElementById('createProduct');
    const root = createRoot(container);
    root.render(
        <React.StrictMode>
            <CreateProduct />
        </React.StrictMode>
    );
}
```

**package.json**
...

```json
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.13.13",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^34.2.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react": "^5.0.2",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.1.1",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.10.2",
    "@table-library/react-table-library": "^4.0.10",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.2",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.0",
    "check-npm": "^1.0.0",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "laravel-mix": "^6.0.49",
    "lodash": "^4.17.19",
    "postcss": "^8.4.14",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.53.0",
    "sass-loader": "^13.0.2",
    "sweetalert2": "^11.4.23",
    "sweetalert2-react-content": "^5.0.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.6",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
}
```

...

**Console Error**
[image: Error on console]

**Browser Output not display toolsbar**
[image: Browser Output]

Comment: Possibly duplicate to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72974217/ckeditor-is-nullgone-when-i-push-f5-refresh-in-react

Comment: @Raman, it's a bit different. For mine, it doesn't show up at all be it initial or refresh.

Answer (score 0):

In my case `CKEditor` wasn't showing at all.

I fixed it by removing `<React.StrictMode>`

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I'll try this and see if it works. All the same, thanks for sharing.

Comment: @EmmanuelJoshua Did it work ?
I also raised an issue on `GitHub` [here](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-react/issues/338)